# Cardinality of minimal generating set of a module is constant

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M$ be a finitely presented module over $R$. Then how to show that for any minimal generating set $S$, the cardinality is same?

Edit: Thanks to Martin to bring into notice about $\mathbb{Z}$ case. I guess I should restrict the statement only to the modules over polynomial rings over a field. So the modified statement:

Let $R$ be a polynomial ring over a field and $M$ be a finitely presented module over $R$. Then how to show that for any minimal generating set $S$, the cardinality is same?

Comment: To ease the work of a potential responder, you may want to include a definition of (or a reference to a definition of) a finitely presented module and a generating set.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. For example, $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are minimal generating sets of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

The same idea for $\mathbb{Z}$ extends to a polynomial ring over a field: for the ideal $(x) \subseteq k[x]$, $\{x\}$ and $\{x^2, x + x^2\}$ are both minimal generating sets.

In general, given a generating set for an ideal $I$, say $I = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, one cannot conclude that $I$ can be generated by a proper subset of the $a_i$, even if $I$ is known to be principal (and even if the ring is a PID).

Comment: I am confused. All this theory of Quillen-Suslin, Complete Intersection, etc depends upon something called as a "minimal number of generators", denoted by $\mu(M)$. So if $\mu$ is not well-defined, then why this whole theory?

Comment: @RobertJones: $\mu_R(M)$ is well-defined for a finitely generated module over a local ring, in which case $\mu_R(M) = \dim_{R/m} (M/mM)$ by Nakayama's lemma. In the local case it is true that if $M$ has a generating set of size $> \mu(M)$, then some subset of that generating set (of size $\mu(M)$) already generates $M$. As you can see by the examples, this last property fails if $R$ is not local